# create a .txt file to a particular directory with c#

Tags: c#

I have written the following program to create a *.txt* file to a particular directory.  But I am not able to create the file. I even changed the path to string `fileName = @"D:\\abc.txt";` ,the program compiles but a file to that particular directory is not created.

Would anyone help me to figure out what could be the error?

```
namespace SimpleLicense
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string fileName = @"C:\\Temp\\abc.txt";

            try
            {
                // Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it. 
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }

                // Create a new file 
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Installed Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    sw.WriteLine("Thermo Licensing System file");

                    DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31);
                    sw.WriteLine("License Expires After"+newDate);

                   // sw.WriteLine("Add ");
                   // sw.WriteLine("Done! ");
                }

                // Write file contents on console. 
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get or catch an exception? If so, what does it say?

Comment: You know that when you use `@`, you do not need to double your slashes, right?

Comment: Also replace File.CreateText(fileName) with new StreamWriter("fileName")

Comment: Can't reproduce. What is the actual error? The only way you can get no file here is if you don't have permissions, or the folder is missing. Otherwise a file is created successfully

Comment: @martennis I am not getting any exception.The program complies fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you're right

Comment: @user2614235 i know it compiles, but when you execute the code, what does is say?

Comment: @martennis I also got no exception. I only got an exception when i was writing in c:\ because I have no permission.

Comment: try sw.Close() and sr.Close() respective place . I know you have used using so no need to close it but still try it

Comment: add a console.readline() just to make sure

Comment: @DhavalPatel not working :(

Comment: Have you tried `sw.Flush()` to finalise writing of the file (below `// sw.WriteLine("Done! ");`)?

Comment: @Ninjapig Thanks my code works fine now without Flush()

Answer (score 6):

You should either do:

```
string fileName = "C:\\Temp\\abc.txt";
```

#### Or

```
string fileName = @"C:\Temp\abc.txt";
```

The @ interprets the string literally so you don't need to escape your backslashes.

### Note:

When I did: `string fileName = @"C:\Users\Shashank\Desktop\test.txt";` (for my computer)

It did work and the text file looks like:

```
Installed Date: 5/19/2014 9:37:08 PM
Thermo Licensing System file
License Expires After6/19/2014 9:37:08 PM
```

You should:

1) Ensure your directory exists - Use an *actual existing* directory
2) Make sure you have writing permissions to that folder

Comment: That is **NOT** the cause of the error. Using `@"C:\\Temp\\abc.txt"` works just fine! The file system does not care about extra backslashes.

Comment: this IS correct but it doesn't answer the question, this is not the reason it isn't working. Whether you using single or double backslashes doesn't make a diff.

Comment: The code works even with the double slashes. This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @sshashank I tried but still not bale to create the file

Comment: @user2614235, See my updated answer and the suggestions at the bottom.

Comment: @sshashank124 still not able to create.I gave the correct location but still.Any issue related to the OS?

Comment: @user2614235, I doubt it. Are you sure your directory exists. Secondly, try putting `Console.WriteLine(somenumber)` statements in different parts of your code and in your `if` blocks to see which parts the code actually "reaches"

Comment: @sshashank124 I rebuilt the solution and now it works fine

Comment: @user2614235, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure that the folder exists.

except for this answers above are ok

Comment: This is one way to reproduce the error. The other is trying to write to a disk's root without administrative permissions

Answer (score 2):

If your program fails, it should throw an exception which will be helpful to diagnose the problem. Please run program in Debugging mode to display the exception.

The problem itself could probably comes from an inexisting directory (Please call "Directory.Create" at the startup if you need to create it) or a lack in permission, please check if user has "Write" permission on folder.

The file could also be locked by another process.

Answer (score 0):

// Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it.

```
   if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
           File.Delete(fileName);
    }

    File.Create("D:\\Yourfile.txt");
```

Comment: using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName)) creates or opens a file for writing. And he is already doing check/delete if exists

Answer (score -2):

Try change

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName)
```

to

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true)
```

and

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName)
```

to

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName)
```

Comment: Why? What difference would it make? How do those changes overcome the current error?

Comment: Your code is absolutely  right. i can create the file by running your code. check c:\ drive carefully.